# How to connect to Cloud Firestore DB with .net core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, google-cloud-firestore

So far all the [examples](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Firestore/userguide.html) of using Google Cloud Firestore with .net show that you connect to your Firestore db by using this command:

```
FirestoreDb db = FirestoreDb.Create(projectId);
```

But is this skipping the step of authentication? I can't seem to find an example of wiring it up to use a Google service account.  I'm guessing you need to connect using the service account's private_key/private_key_id/client_email?

Comment: It looks like you might create a GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable and then set the contents of the service account credentials json file to that variable per this [documentation](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Firestore/index.html), I'm giving that a try now.

Comment: Google docs are really bad...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But is this skipping the step of authentication?

No. It will use the default application credentials. If you're running on Google Cloud Platform (AppEngine, GCE or GKE), they will just be the default service account credentials for the instance. Otherwise, you should set the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable to refer to a service account credential file.

From the [home page of the user guide](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Firestore/index.html) you referred to:

> When running on Google Cloud Platform, no action needs to be taken to authenticate.
>
> Otherwise, the simplest way of authenticating your API calls is to download a service account JSON file then set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable to refer to it. The credentials will automatically be used to authenticate. See the Getting Started With Authentication guide for more details.

It's somewhat more awkward to use *non-default* credentials; [this recent issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-dotnet/issues/2349) gives an example.

Comment: thanks for the response!  The problem I'm running into now is how to get the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable to point correctly to the json file in my .net core app. I think I'll try what they did in that link you provided for non-default credentials, that might work better for me for other reasons as well.

Comment: @mkimmet: It's considerable more work in general. What problem are you having setting the environment variable? It should be straightforward...

Comment: I've got it working based on the non-default credential link you provided, However, I've tried both appsettings.json and the VS user secrets, and put in a reference to "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS": "my-firestore-credentials.json"  and also tried with "./" and "~/" before the file name and still get the error: *InvalidOperationException: The Application Default Credentials are not available...the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials.* I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong with the path or environment variable

Comment: @mkimmet: Those are ASP.NET Core settings - that's not the same as setting an environment variable. We don't know how you're running your code, which makes it harder to know how to advise to set the environment variable, unfortunately. In a `Dockerfile` for example, you'd just use an `ENV` directive. You should look for documentation about setting environment variables in your particular execution environment. (This would be very general documentation - nothing to do with ASP.NET Core or Firestore.)

Comment: That makes sense, I guess I'm getting my "environment" variables mixed up.  I'll  have to do more research on what it takes to do _real_ environment variables with the way I have .net core set up.  Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

You can also use the credentials stored in a json file:

```
    GoogleCredential cred = GoogleCredential.FromFile("credentials.json");
    Channel channel = new Channel(FirestoreClient.DefaultEndpoint.Host,
                  FirestoreClient.DefaultEndpoint.Port,
                  cred.ToChannelCredentials());
    FirestoreClient client = FirestoreClient.Create(channel);
    FirestoreDb db = FirestoreDb.Create("my-project", client);
```

Comment: I didn't tried it - maybe. I'm disappointed from Firestore's performance in general (takes ~500ms per query), so we stopped using it anyway.

Comment: @cdaiga we moved to BigTable - it's performance is outstanding (so is the pricing...)

Answer (score 12):

I could not compile @Michael Bleterman's code, however the following worked for me:

```cs
using Google.Cloud.Firestore;
using Google.Cloud.Firestore.V1;


var jsonString = File.ReadAllText(_keyFilepath);
var builder = new FirestoreClientBuilder {JsonCredentials = jsonString};
FirestoreDb db = FirestoreDb.Create(_projectId, builder.Build());
```

Packages I use:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Google.Cloud.Firestore" Version="2.0.0-beta02" />
<PackageReference Include="Google.Cloud.Storage.V1" Version="2.5.0" />
```

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me.

https://pieterdlinde.medium.com/netcore-and-cloud-firestore-94628943eb3c

```
string filepath = "/Users/user/Downloads/user-a4166-firebase-adminsdk-ivk8q-d072fdf334.json";
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", filepath);
fireStoreDb = FirestoreDb.Create("user-a4166");
```

Comment: I found your call to `GetAwaiter` useful to avoid await/async: `QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = query.GetSnapshotAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();`

Comment: @Shadi That's not a good idea. http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way:

Get [service account json file](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize-sdk) and hardcode values into a class:

```
    public class FirebaseSettings
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("project_id")]
        public string ProjectId => "that-rug-really-tied-the-room-together-72daa";
    
        [JsonPropertyName("private_key_id")]
        public string PrivateKeyId => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    
        // ... and so on
    }
```

Add it `Startup.cs`

```
var firebaseJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new FirebaseSettings());

services.AddSingleton(_ => new FirestoreProvider(
    new FirestoreDbBuilder 
    { 
        ProjectId = firebaseSettings.ProjectId, 
        JsonCredentials = firebaseJson // <-- service account json file
    }.Build()
));
```

Add wrapper `FirebaseProvider`

```
public class FirestoreProvider
{
    private readonly FirestoreDb _fireStoreDb = null!;

    public FirestoreProvider(FirestoreDb fireStoreDb)
    {
        _fireStoreDb = fireStoreDb;
    }

    // ... your methods here

}
```

Here is a full example of a generic provider.

https://dev.to/kedzior_io/simple-net-core-and-cloud-firestore-setup-1pf9